# Identify small black cubic component with 2 pins

Tags: components, identification

I found this component between my supply of resistors, motors, Arduino etc: (ruler for scale)
[image: Image of the component]

It is a small black cuboid (.4cm x .4cm x .2cm) with 2 pins (1.7cm) connected to it. On the front face is written in white:

```
2C1
100V
83 26
```

On the top:

```
470pK
```

Does somebody know what component this is and what the numbers written on it mean?

Comment: 100 V 470pF capacitor.

Comment: @winny So can it handle a voltage of 100V? Seems a lot to me for such a small component?

Comment: Yes it can. Try it!

Comment: tolerance 10%, for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a 47 pF 100 V capacitor.

Capacitance values on small parts like this are almost always expressed in a floating point format.  In this case, most likely, the first two digits are the mantissa and the last the exponent of 10.  "470" therefore means "47 x 10<sup>0</sup>".  We guess that the units is pF, but that is almost universally the case.

Comment: What does the pK mean?

Comment: @Todd: Not sure without a datasheet.  "p" might indicate picofarads, and "K" could be a temperature range.  Just guessing though.